# Pandas: adding a MultiIndex to a DataFrame consisting of only 1 row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a small dataframe such as follow:

[image]

and a tuple such as : `(Timestamp('2009-02-27 09:45:00'), 'bloomberg', 'Chicago PMI')`

I would like to create a multindex on the DataFrame so that it reads something like:

[image]

When trying to construct the MultiIndex:
`MI=pd.MultiIndex(index, (0,0,0))`
 I encounter the following error:
`TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, Timestamp('2009-02-27 09:45:00') was passed`
 which seems to mean it is not allowed to have a 1 row DataFrame with a MultiIndex?

I am iterating over a mysql db to retrieve those 1 row DataFrame to then concatenate them. Trying to use the `keys` argument from the concat command create another set of problems, so hopefully it is possible to create this 1 row DataFrame with MultiIndex

Here below the data to reconstruct the dataframe:
`import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp
dikt={'actual': {0: '34.2'}, 'previous': {0: '33.3'}, 'forecast': {0: '33.0'}, 'importance': {0: 81.300799999999995}}
pd.DataFrame(dikt, columns=['actual', 'forecast', 'previous', 'importance'])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***setup***

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[34.2, 33., 33.3, 81.3008]],
    columns=['actual', 'forecast', 'previous', 'importance'])

tup = (pd.Timestamp('2009-02-27 09:45:00'), 'bloomberg', 'Chicago PMI')
```

***reassign the index with a `pd.MultiIndex` object***

```
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([tup])
df
```

[image]

***reassign the index with list of lists***

```
df.index = [[i] for i in tup]
df
```

[image]

***completely horrible way using `rename`***
***THIS IS BAD BECAUSE IT ASSIGNS SAME `TUPLE` TO EVERY ROW***

```
df.rename(index=lambda x: tup)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
df.index = pd.MultiIndex(
    [[Timestamp('2009-02-27 09:45:00')], 
     ['bloomberg'], ['Chicago PMI']], [[0], [0], [0]], names = [
        'timestamp', 'agency', 'item'])
print(df)
                                         actual forecast previous  importance
timestamp           agency    item                                            
2009-02-27 09:45:00 bloomberg Chicago PMI   34.2     33.0     33.3     81.3008
```